# How to use AWS ELB as a output for Filebeat?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash, amazon-elb, filebeat

I have a setup where a number of beat agents are sending files to Amazon ELB , the ELB then sends the traffic to 2 Logstash servers. I am trying out the following configuration to work this out but i this doesn't seem to work at all:

`

```
output:
    logstash:
        # The Logstash hosts
        hosts: ["logstash-loadbalancer-1358451793.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com:5044"]

        # Number of workers per Logstash host.
        worker: 2
```

`

I have gone through some posts where people have done something similar but these also don't clearly mention the config.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-i-add-loadbalance-to-filebeat-config-for-hosts-in-logstash-output/53378/5

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-only-goes-to-one-of-the-logstash-servers-that-is-behind-an-elb/48875/8

Can someone help out?

Comment: Define *"doesn't seem to work."*

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am not able to get anything out of Logstash servers to my ES

Comment: What do you see in the [ELB access logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/access-log-collection.html)?  Can you connect to the elb manually? `telnet elb-hostbame 5044`? Are the instances showing "healthy" in the ELB?

Comment: yes elbs are good

Comment: Run Filebeat and enable debug logging. For Filebeat 5.x installed via rpm/deb it would be: `./filebeat.sh -e -d "*"`. Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well, my issue was that my ELB wasn't listening on that port (5044). I added a 5044 <-> 5044 TCP listener and filebeat was able to connect to logstash through the ELB.